# Псевдоэелемент ::after у ссылки в списке

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Есть следующая задача: создать список, в `<li>` которого есть ссылка `<a>`, у которой псевдоэлемент `::after` находится правее первой строки. 
Выглядеть это должно вот так: 
[image: Список]

Что делаю я:

```css
.content {
        width: 230px; /*того требует макет*/
}
.list {
    display: inline-block;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 0; 
}
    
.li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px; 
}
    
a {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: fit-content;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #2e2e2e; 
}
a::after {
      content: "";
      display: inline;
      position: absolute;
      top: 9px;
      right: -8px;
      width: 4px;
      height: 4px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #1ea9e7; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <ul class="list">
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Остальное</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

И вот, что при этом происходит:

[image: Что происходит?]

Фактически, мне нужно, чтобы ссылка ограничивалась по ширине своей первой строкой (как бы глупо это ни звучало), и тогда проблема решится, но несмотря на её `inline-block`'овость, она растягивается на 100% ширины родителя, и `::after` появляется не там, где нужно. 
  Сделать `<li>` строчным или строчно-блочным не является решением, так как есть ещё списки, в которых это приведёт к переходу элементов списка на одну строку.
Сделать `<a>` строчным также не является решением, `::after` будет привязываться к концу фактической строки, а не к концу первой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не смог больше ждать и решил сделать всё напрямую - скриптом. Он перебирает все элементы `<li class="li">` на странице и разбивает каждую строку его `<a>` на отдельный `<span>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $('.li').length; i++) {
    var spanInserted = $($('.li').eq(i).children('a')).html().split(" ").join(" </span><span>");
    var wrapped = ("<span>").concat(spanInserted, "</span>");
    $($('li').eq(i).children('a')).html(wrapped);
    var refPos = $('.li a span:first-child').position().top;
    var newPos;
    $('.li a span').each(function(index) {
      newPos = $(this).position().top
      if (index == 0) {
        return;
      }
      if (newPos == refPos) {
        $(this).prepend($(this).prev().text() + " ");
        $(this).prev().remove();
      }
      refPos = newPos;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 230px;
  /*того требует макет*/
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 0;
}

.li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span:first-child {
  position: relative;
}

span:first-child::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: -8px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1ea9e7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Остальное</a></li>
    <li class="li"><a href="#">Планирование и бюджетирование</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

После этого первому `span` этого `<a>` даётся `::after`. Подкорректированные стили выше. Возможно, это и костыль, но лучше ничего не нашёл.